# How to use Apache Httpclient with Jersey 2.3 client

Tags: java, apache, ssl, jersey

I would like to use an Apache connector with Jersey 2.3 client for HTTPS connections.

I tried the following:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, new PoolingClientConnectionManager());

ApacheConnector connector = new ApacheConnector(clientConfig);  
clientConfig.connector(connector);  

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .withConfig(clientConfig)
    .sslContext(sslContext)
    .hostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier())
    .build();
```

However, it seems the sslContext is ignored as the certificate of the server is rejected as untrusted (sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target)

If I remove the ".withConfig(clientConfig)" part, the SSL connection works fine, but evidently without the Apache connector. Is there a way to use my own ClientConfig with the Apache connector as well as my own SSLContext?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need config SSL for apache connector.

```java
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.CONNECTION_MANAGER, new PoolingClientConnectionManager());
//config your ssl for apache connector
SslConfigurator sslConfig = SslConfigurator.newInstance();
clientConfig.property(ApacheClientProperties.SSL_CONFIG, sslConfig);

ApacheConnector connector = new ApacheConnector(clientConfig);  
clientConfig.connector(connector);  

Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
.withConfig(clientConfig)
.hostnameVerifier(getHostnameVerifier())
.build();
```

Comment: That works! The only problem for me is that this class org.glassfish.jersey.SslConfigurator does not allow to select the cipher that is used. I'd need something like
    sslConfigurator.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] { "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256", "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA" });

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whay are you using apache connector. But you can make a client connection using jersey and https like this:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
ctx.init(null, myTrustManager, null);
config.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new HTTPSProperties(hostnameVerifier, ctx));
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

Comment: I will try that out, thanks! The reason I am using the Apache connector is that I want to support to use HTTP proxy with username and password. I did not find a way to do that without the Apache connector.

Comment: It looks like what you propose is the old Jersey 1.0 syntax, not 2.x

Comment: One reason could be that https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.23/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/client/HttpUrlConnectorProvider.html#SET_METHOD_WORKAROUND doesn't work on IBM's JVM.